# more than one line of text centered on both sides of a vertical line

Tags: tables

I want more lines of text on both sides of a vertical line. The text lines should be vertically centered. Normally, if I only need one line of text on one side, this code works great. But, if I want to have a second line and use `\\`, it doesn't work. I want the two words in the middle of my MWE to be in two separate lines, vertically centered, to the left and to the right of the vertical line.
How can I fix that problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|}
plus \\
moins \\
aussi \\
\end{tabular}
+ adjectif
\begin{tabular}{l|}
\\
\\
\\
\end{tabular}
+que

\vspace{24pt}


\begin{tabular}{l|}
plus \\
moins \\
aussi \\
\end{tabular}
+ adjectif\\
+adverbe
\begin{tabular}{l|}
\\
\\
\\
\end{tabular}
+que

\vspace{24pt}

\begin{tabular}{l|}
Bien qu'\\
Quoiqu'\\
\end{tabular}
elle \textbf{soit} malade, elle continue de travailler.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's too many lines in this question :D Could you try to clarify what lines you are talking about? Currently I don't understand the problem. E.g., you could try to use `vline` consequently for the vertical lines of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you like this one? Choose a better name than `foo`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{foo}
 {\def\\{\cr\noalign{\hskip1em\vrule\hskip1em}}%
  \def\obj##1{\hbox{\strut##1}}%
  \valign\bgroup&\vfill##\vfill\cr}
 {\crcr\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
\obj{plus} \obj{moins} \obj{aussi} \\
\obj{+ adjectif} \\
\obj{+ que}
\end{foo}

\bigskip

\begin{foo}
\obj{plus} \obj{moins} \obj{aussi} \\
\obj{+ adjectif} \obj{+ adverbe} \\
\obj{+ que}
\end{foo}

\bigskip

\begin{foo}
\obj{Bien qu'} \obj{Quoiqu'} \\
\obj{elle \textbf{soit} malade, elle continue de travailler.}
\end{foo}


\end{document}
```

[image]

With nested `tabular`s; more complicated code but friendlier syntax: columns are separated by `\\`, items in each column are separated by `&` (they could be switched if preferred).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewEnviron{foo}
 {
  \katharina_foo:V \BODY
 }

\seq_new:N \l__katharina_foo_columns_seq
\seq_new:N \l__katharina_foo_column_seq
\seq_new:N \l__katharina_foo_body_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \katharina_foo:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__katharina_foo_columns_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__katharina_foo_body_seq
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__katharina_foo_columns_seq \__katharina_foo_column:n
  \begin{tabular}
   {
    @{}
    l
    *{ \int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l__katharina_foo_columns_seq - 1 } } { |l }
    @{}
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__katharina_foo_body_seq { & }
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \katharina_foo:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__katharina_foo_column:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__katharina_foo_column_seq { & } { #1 }
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l__katharina_foo_body_seq
   {
    \exp_not:n { \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} }
    \seq_use:Nn \l__katharina_foo_column_seq { \\ }
    \exp_not:n { \end{tabular} }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
plus & moins & aussi \\
+ adjectif \\
+ que
\end{foo}

\bigskip

\begin{foo}
plus & moins & aussi \\
+ adjectif & + adverbe \\
+ que
\end{foo}

\bigskip

\begin{foo}
Bien qu' & Quoiqu' \\
elle \textbf{soit} malade, elle continue de travailler.
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `\\` between `+adjectif` and `+adverbe` works differently from the ones between `plus`, `moins` and `aussi` because you're not inside a `tabular` there.
It breaks the current line and this includes the entire `tabular` preceding it, causing `+adverbe` to appear below `aussi`.

You're using a `tabular` with empty entries to create a vertical line that spans three lines, but you could also wrap a `tabular` with just one row around the entire thing to do this. You can then nest `tabular`s that have just one column inside of these to take care of the columns, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% N.B. these lines are not necessary; they were copied from the question
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        plus \\ moins \\ aussi
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        +adjectif \\ +adverbe
    \end{tabular}
    &
    +autre chose
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the `@{}` in the column declarations of the inner `tabular`s. These suppress the space that would otherwise be inserted between columns (and before/after the first/last column).

[image]

P.S. You're loading `babel` with the `ngerman` option but your text appears to be in French. Is this a mistake or are you writing a text in one language about another language?

Comment: I'm writing in german with french examples.

Comment: @Katharina: makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like
the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[french,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <- added
\usepackage{varwidth}% <- added
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\newcommand{\tcell}[1]{% sets up a box containing the text given as argument, vertically centered
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}% max width of the box will be \linewidth
  \strut#1\strut% the struts are neccessary to get the correct height and depth of the box (and hence the vertical lines)
\end{varwidth}}


\begin{document}

Deutscher Text.

\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
  plus &&\\
  moins & + adjectif & +que\\
  aussi &&
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
  \tcell{plus\\moins\\aussi} &
  \tcell{+ adjectif\\+ adverbe} &
  +que
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l|l|l}% if you don't like the space on the left
\tcell{plus\\moins\\aussi} &
\tcell{+ adjectif\\+ adverbe} &
+que
\end{tabular}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
Weiter in deutsch.

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l}
    \tcell{Bien qu'\\Quoiqu'} & elle \textbf{soit} malade, elle continue de travailler.
  \end{tabular}

  \begin{tabular}{l|}
    Bien qu'\\
    Quoiqu'\\
  \end{tabular}
  elle \textbf{soit} malade, elle continue de travailler.
\end{otherlanguage}


\end{document}
```

I created the new command `\tcell` (you can rename it to your liking)
which creates a varwidth-minipage containing your text. The varwidth
package needs to be loaded for this. It adjusts the width of the
minipage to the text. You need to specify the maximum width, I used
`\linewidth` here, after which the text will be broken to a new line.

**Note:** I modified the languages you load, as it seems you want
to use German as well as French in your document. The last language
specified is the default language loaded at the beginning. You can
change the language in multiple ways. I included two examples. I
highly recommend the [LaTeX/Internationalization](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization) article in
Wikipedia. Also, I added the `fontenc` package, to display all
accents correctly.